# RegularExpressionAttribute always fails

Tags: c#, regex

I have following code to test a class property:

```
public class RegExtTest
{
   [RegularExpression(@"^[A-z0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "Lot must be 6 characters alphanumeric")]
    public string Lot { get; set; }
}
```

and a generic extension method to validate a class containing one or more of these objects

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ValidateObject(this object objectToValidate)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var objType = objectToValidate.GetType();
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var attrs = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
            foreach (var attribue in attrs)
            {
                try
                {
                    var validationAttr = attribue as ValidationAttribute;
                    if (validationAttr != null)
                    {
                        validationAttr.Validate(objectToValidate,propertyInfo.Name);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e is ValidationException)
                        result.Add(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

However validation fails when value is "a23456". I unit tested this using Regex class as follows:

```
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(lbp.Lot, "^[A-z0-9]{6}$");
```

The above test passes. 
What am i doing wrong here? Is there some gotcha in RegularExpressionAttribute I am not aware off

Comment: Are you sure [A-z] is valid?? Don't you want to be using [A-Za-z0-9] instead?

Comment: What do you mean "validation fails" when `a23456` passes? That's a 6-character alphanumeric string, so it should pass, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `Validate` method wrong.

Instead of

```
validationAttr.Validate(objectToValidate,propertyInfo.Name);
```

use

```
validationAttr.Validate(propertyInfo.GetValue(objectToValidate, null),propertyInfo.Name);
```

You have to pass the *actual value* of the property to the `Validate` method, since the `RegularExpressionAttribute` class will just call `.ToString()` on the `value` argument and check it against its pattern.

But it's still easiest to use the [`Validator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx), [as Jay already said in his answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974176/142637)

Comment: tx. that was spot on. I am using v3.5, so cant use validator.

Comment: The other thing I would suggest is catching `ValidationException` explicitly in your `try...catch`. As it is any other errors that are thrown would be swallowed!

Comment: i understand but I am not putting all other errors in the log. this was just  a prototype. final version logs all other exceptions

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your implementation by using the `Validator`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) for more details.

This should do the trick.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ValidateObject(this object model)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(model);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, true);
    return results.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage);
}
```

**Update**

I originally forgot the additional `true` (validateAllProperties) at the end of the call to `TryValidateObject`. The `true` specifies the validator to check every property and every `ValidationAttribute`.

I tested this against you use case `Lot = "a12345"` which works (does not return an error message) v.s. `Lot = "a1234$"` which does return an error message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention I am in .net 3.5